# How to rebase and resolve conflicts in sourcetree

Tags: git, branch, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree, conflict

Starting situation is:

[image]

Now I want to rebase 'work' (and 'origin/work') onto 'master'
So I checked out 'work' locally and right click 'master' and select the option 'rebase current changes onto master'

[image]

Because there is a conflict, I get the following message:

[image]

and the following situation:

[image]

After I have resolved the conflicts in eclipse and staged them

Question 1:
Do I have to commit the changes or click Actions -> Continue rebase

When I do the last one I get the following situation:

[image]

Question 2: Why do I have 1 pull request after rebasing and what do I have to do next?
Pulling gives me a very strange tree, which I don't want.

[image]

Pushing gives an error, or do I have to force push?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to commit, then your rebase should be complete.
2. You now have diverged from the branch in origin. If you are happy with your result you should force push. E.g. `git push --force`. If you want to use sorucetree to do it, you need to enable the option in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Fix the conflicts in the files
2. Move all affected files to staged and do NOT commit them
3. Choose Actions - Continue rebase